# How to exec a forever running update statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I want to keep updating the values in a table FOREVER, how can I do that?

For example I have a table:

```
ID | Col 1 | Col 2
---+-------+-------
1  |    123|   321
2  |    231|   321
3  |    333|   321
4  |    113|   321
5  |    153|   321
```

After running the statement:

1 second later:

```
ID | Col 1 | Col 2
---+-------+-------
1  |    222|   321
2  |    233|   321
3  |    133|   321
4  |    123|   321
5  |    183|   321
```

2 seconds later:

```
ID | Col 1 | Col 2
---+-------+-------
1  |    444|   321
2  |    253|   321
3  |    233|   321
4  |    183|   321
5  |     93|   321
```

N seconds later:

```
ID | Col 1 | Col 2
---+-------+-------
1  |    324|   321
2  |    383|   321
3  |    343|   321
4  |    530|   321
5  |    193|   321
```

Note that the values are not important here, I just want them to keep updating in a non transactional manner, forever.

What am I trying to achieve by doing this? I don't know. Just wondering if this can be done and no I am not looking for a trigger.

Comment: "*What am I trying to achieve by doing this? I don't know.*" You are asking us to create the solution for a problem that doesn't exist. There is no logical reason why you would **want** to indefinitely overwrite data in a database with random data. Much less doing it automatically every second, putting strain on the server.

Comment: set up scheduler to update the data every second >_>

Comment: @ObsidianAge If you somehow has the access to your competitor's db, you might **want** to do that just to mess with them.

Comment: That would be illegal. Unless you're advocating a crime?

Comment: It can be done. However after reading your conversation with ObsidianAge in the comments I'm not convinced *you* should know how to do it.

Comment: Asking how to do it doesn't mean you're going to do it, please don't divert the attention. Many people know sudo rm -rf /, and I don't think there's a logical reason behind it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute your query recursively by creating a job in sql server, in this you can mention time for recursive for every seconds or min or day etc.